# Circuit diagram to convert instrument level to mic level

Tags: voltage, divider

I have a wireless mic transmitter/receiver system that I would like to use to connect to an acoustic electric guitar instead of a microphone.

This isn’t part of the problem but will describe the setup. It’s a Rode Wireless GO II mic system. Great distance, good reviews on the product.

I was looking for a wireless mic headset and wireless guitar setup as a combined set, but everything I looked at had a separate transmitter and receiver. I was trying to make this really small and portable (think campfire… not stage quality). I came across this Rode system. It’s really compact. It has 2 very small/light transmitters and a single receiver. I was thinking I could plug a headset mic into one transmitter, the guitar into the other transmitter and then the single receiver into whatever speaker I use.

Anyway. Onto the technical part.

From what I’ve been able to read there are 4 main different levels of audio signal (mic, instrument, line, speaker).
I’m assuming the signal from a guitar is instrument.

From the searches I’ve done there are tons of adapters you can buy (and DIY circuit diagrams) to convert line to mic but I haven’t found a single reference (or diagram) for instrument to mic.

Would a simple voltage divider work?  And if so, would anyone have a a diagram?

Last note: I hope to make it a simple resistive circuit as I was planning on building the circuit into a cable. I need to adapt between the standard 1/4" guitar TRS to a 3.5 mm mic TRS.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a DI (Direct Inject) box. There are two main types, passive and active.

Comment: In theory a resistive attenuator would be ok, but 1) You may want also to equalize to separate well the guitar sound from the mic sound and that surely depends on the performed music. I guess you do not want to walk to the speaker mixer to do it. 2) Rode's datasheets do not reveal what mutes the on-the-box-mic and takes the external mic into use. At worst there's a proprietary sensing system which accepts only Rode's mics. That's a way to keep low cost 3rd party stuff out. Ask Rode support or a big enough music gear seller. 3) Is the latency (not specified) short enough for your purposes?